# Remove spaces from string but not all

Tags: php

To be clear, i want this:

> Europe    Qualicitaions

to transform to this:

> Europe Qualifications

I getting data from xml feed, and some strings like this up has more than one space, problem is that i don't know how many spaces will be in string, so i want to remove all spaces before, and after string, also remove separator spaces from middle more than one, i want to have one space in middle, but no 2,3-10...

Answer (score 1):

```
$newstring = preg_replace('/(\s+)/', ' ', $str);
```